# How to map two tables in the same class with non-primary-key

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

I Have this class:

```
public class Account
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Balance { get; set; }
    public virtual int IdExternalAccount { get; set; }
}
```

that represents the tabble Account in my db.

The point is that i need to map the property Balance to references an especified property of other table named V_DEBITACCOUNT.

```
CREATE TABLE V_DEBITACCOUNT (
IDACCOUNT NUMERIC(19,0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
BALANCE NUMERIC(18,4) NULL
)
```

The field IDACCOUNT on table V_DEBITACCOUNT references the field IdExternalAccount in Account.

I have made this mapping that works partly.

```
Table("WTBR_CVW.ACCOUNT");
            Id(x => x.Id, m =>
            {
                m.Generator(Generators.Sequence, p => p.Params(new { sequence = "WTBR_CVW.SQACCOUNT" }));
                m.Column("IDACCOUNT");
            });

Property(
                x => x.IdExternalAccount,
                m => m.Column("IDEXTERNALACCOUNT"));

Join("WTBR_CVW.ACCOUNT",
               m =>
               {
                   m.Table("WTBR_CVW.V_DEBITACCOUNT");
                   m.Optional(true);

                   m.Key(x =>
                   {
                       x.PropertyRef(pr => pr.IdExternalAccount);
                       x.Column("IDACCOUNT");
                   });

                   m.Property<decimal>(x => x.Balance, map =>
                   {
                       map.Column("AVAILABLEBALANCE");
                   });

                   m.Property<System.DateTime>(x => x.ReferenceDate, map =>
                  {
                      map.Column("LASTUPDATETIME");
                  });

               });
```

the problems is that the PropertyRef doesn't works. The join is considering the Id defined in PrimeryKey of Account and ignore that a specified.

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'd suggest to map it partially with .hmb.xml ... to be sure that the concept is working (xml is proven, if that won't work, no other way). And if JOIN will work with xml - not by code - use it. Other option is to go with one-to-one

Answer (score 1):

You are doing nothing wrong here. It is a [unsupported feature](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-1452) of NHibernate, which will be fixed in upcoming 4.1.0 version.